# How to call another method in the pojo class setter method [session file uploading application] of Hibernate and struts 2

Tags: database, image, hibernate, struts2

Hi Friends i am developing an web application which uses hibernate and struts2. i am creating photo album i successfully done that with out using hibernate but, with hibernate it is having problem while inserting to the database. the module works like this as soon as the file uploaded it will insert the FileName, Contenttype,id and it suppose to insert the Image File(byte[]) Content also but it is showing Null in table value.. my code  goes like this...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PHOTOALBUM")
public class User implements Serializable  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="PHOTO_ID")
    private Long id;

@Column(name="IMAGE")
private byte[] Image;


@Column(name="CONTENT_TYPE")
    private String userImageContentType;

@Column(name="PHOTO_NAME")
    private String userImageFileName;

            public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

            public String getUserImageFileName() {
        return userImageFileName;
    }

    public void setUserImageFileName(String userImageFileName) {
        this.userImageFileName = userImageFileName;
    }

            public String getUserImageContentType() {
        return userImageContentType;
    }

    public void setUserImageContentType(String userImageContentType) {
        this.userImageContentType = userImageContentType;
    }

public byte[] getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] Image) {
        Image=Change(this.getUserImage());
        this.Image = Image;
    }

    @Transient
    private File userImage;

    public File getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(File userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public byte[] Change(File userImage)
    {
       // userImage=this.getUserImage();
       // String name=userImage.getName();
       // long len=userImage.length();

        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) userImage.length()];
        try {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(userImage);
    fileInputStream.read(bFile);
    fileInputStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       // System.out.println("The Name Of File In Pojo Class Is:="+ name);
        //System.out.println("The Length Of File In Pojo Class Is:="+ len);
        //System.out.println("The Content Of File In Pojo Class Is:="+ bFile);
        return bFile;
    }

}
```

and i am  saving the values  like this

```
 public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@SessionTarget
Session session;

@TransactionTarget
Transaction transaction;

/**
 * Used to save or update a user.
 */
@Override
public void saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Used to delete a user.
 */
@Override
public void deleteUser(Long userId) {
    try {
        User user = (User) session.get(User.class, userId);
        session.delete(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

/**
 * Used to list all the users.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<User> listUser() {
    List<User> courses = null;
    try {
        courses = session.createQuery("from User").list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return courses;
}

/**
 * Used to list a single user by Id.
 */
@Override
public User listUserById(Long userId) {
    User user = null;
    try {
        user = (User) session.get(User.class, userId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}

}
```

the struts action mapping goes like this...

```
 \<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
<action name="saveOrUpdateUser"method="saveOrUpdate"class="com.srikanth.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
    </action>
    <action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.srikanth.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="editUser" method="edit" class="com.srikanth.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="deleteUser" method="delete" class="com.srikanth.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

and my jsp goes like this

```
 \<s:form action="saveOrUpdateUser">
<s:push value="user">
    <s:hidden name="id" />
    <s:file name="userImage" label="User Image" />
            <s:submit />
</s:push>
 </s:form>
 <s:iterator value="userList" status="userStatus">
        <s:property value="id" />
            <s:property value="userImageFileName" />
            <s:property value="userImageContentType" />
            <img src='<s:property value="userImage" />' alt"" />
            <s:url id="deleteURL" action="deleteUser">
                <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
            </s:url> <s:a href="%{deleteURL}">Delete</s:a>
    </s:iterator>
```

I am trying to call the Change Method so that it convert the file to byte[] and stored it in byte[] Image variable using setter but it is not working....
So please help me with this one .....
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per my understand of question the problem is only inserting file into table. Copy & paste the Change() method into com.srikanth.web.UserAction class as you are using this action for every DB transaction. use Change() method before going to insert/update in DB.

For example:

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport{
   //variable to get file from jsp
   private File uploadedImage;
    .....
   //setters & getters for uploadedImage


@Override
public String gsexecute() throws Exception {

   User user = new User();

   //set image value as byteArray
   user.setImage(Change(uploadedImage));

   //insert or update DB here

    return SUCCESS;
}

 public byte[] Change(File userImage)
   {
   // userImage=this.getUserImage();
   // String name=userImage.getName();
   // long len=userImage.length();

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) userImage.length()];
    try {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(userImage);
fileInputStream.read(bFile);
fileInputStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   // System.out.println("The Name Of File In Pojo Class Is:="+ name);
    //System.out.println("The Length Of File In Pojo Class Is:="+ len);
    //System.out.println("The Content Of File In Pojo Class Is:="+ bFile);
    return bFile;
   }

 }
```

And make sure that the table column should support the byte array insert. Ex: use BLOB column type for MYSQL.